# Asynchronous transfer message between two clients

Tags: c, client, message, transfer

This time I code a chat server and client. The idea is this.

The server uses the select method for with a readfd(FD_SET) to seek which of the clients connected on it have something to send. If it founds something it send it to the rest of clients.

Here is the select function on server and a part of server's [code](http://pastebin.com/mG0SmFCT).

```
SelectResults = select(maxDescriptor+1,&BackUpfdread,NULL,NULL,&time);
```

I use the select function in client too, to make it seek for incoming and outcoming messages.(these that server sends from other clients and these that this client want to send).

Well, the client in the select function has a fdread and fdwrite (FD_SET).

[Here](http://pastebin.com/YtLUrLcq) is the part of the code that client has for the connection and for the chat.

The problem is that if i connect two clients on the server message transfer isn't concurrent and that means that clients cannot chat correctly.

Finally i thought to use threads in server. One thread for waiting to receive and one for sending to the clients, but i want to hear and your opinion.

Comment: You do make the listening and client sockets in the server nonblocking?

Comment: Sorry but i cannot understand your question.

Comment: It might have nothing to do with the blocking or non-blocking status of the sockets (use Google search to find out what it means), but if I understand your question correctly your server works when only one client is connected but does not work when two clients are connected? Then it's a problem in the server not the client. Can you edit your question to include small relevant pieces of the server code (like how you call `select` and `accept`, and how you read data from clients and send data to clients)?

Comment: The server always works. With one or more clients. The problem is that the clients didn't get the messages on time. Ok i edited the post above. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

In the client you don't really need that loop from 0 to `maxDescriptor`. Just check if `ConnectSocket` is set. Something like this:

```
// Main loop starts here
for(; ;)
{
  memset(SentBuff, 0, sizeof(SentBuff));
  printf("Write: ");
  gets_s(SentBuff, sizeof(SentBuff));

  // Copy the fdread into BackUpfdread and fdwrite to BackUpfdwrite.
  BackUpfdread = fdread;
  BackUpfdwrite = fdwrite;

  SelectResults = select(maxDescriptor+1,&BackUpfdread,&BackUpfdwrite,NULL,&timer);

  if(SelectResults == -1)
  {
    perror("Client-select() error!\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  if (FD_ISSET(ConnectSocket, &BackUpfdread))
  {
    RecvBytes = recv(ConnectSocket, RecvBuff, sizeof(RecvBuff), 0);
    if(RecvBytes > 0)
    {
      printf("%s\n",RecvBuff);
      // Cleaning the Receive Buffer
      memset(RecvBuff,0,sizeof(RecvBuff));
    }
  }

  if (FD_ISSET(ConnectSocket, &BackUpfdwrite))
  {
    SentBytes = send(ConnectSocket, SentBuff,sizeof(SentBuff),0);
    // Cleaning the Sent Buffer
    memset(SentBuff,0,sizeof(SentBuff));
  }
} // Main loop ends here
```

Also don't forget to check for errors from `send` and `recv`. Especially `recv` is important, as it's the call that will tell you the server has disconnected.

**Edit:** Another important thing to note, is that the socket may be writeable always, so add a check if there is something to write before you check if the socket is writeable.